# How to Get the "Content" of any Control in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I am coding a function which will take a `Control Ctrl` as `Arguement` and Modify the `Control.Content` of it.
Is there Any way to Get and Set the `Content` of any `Control`??

Code :

```
void RemoveHotKey(Control Ctrl, int KeyIndex)
{
    if (Ctrl.Content.ToString().Substring(KeyIndex, 1) == "_") // System.Windows.Controls.Control does not contain a definition for 'Content'
    {
        Ctrl.Content = Ctrl.Content.ToString().Remove(KeyIndex, 1); // System.Windows.Controls.Control does not contain a definition for 'Content'
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you using a Control class argument instead of a ContentControl class argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this instead:

```
void RemoveHotKey(ContentControl Ctrl, int KeyIndex) 
{ 
    if (Ctrl.Content.ToString().Substring(KeyIndex, 1) == "_")
    { 
        Ctrl.Content = Ctrl.Content.ToString().Remove(KeyIndex, 1);
    } 
}
```

take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx).

or this:

```
void RemoveHotKey(Control Ctrl, int KeyIndex)
{
    ContentControl contentCtrl = Ctrl as ContentControl;
    if (contentCtrl != null && contentCtrl.Content != null)
    {
        if (contentCtrl.Content.ToString().Substring(KeyIndex, 1) == "_")
        { 
            contentCtrl.Content = contentCtrl.Content.ToString().Remove(KeyIndex, 1);
        }
    } 
}
```

which is way less expensive than using reflection..

Answer (score 2):

You could change the signature of your method to this:

```
void RemoveHotKey(ContentControl Ctrl, int KeyIndex)
```

a [`ContentControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx) always has a [`Content`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content.aspx) property.

Answer (score 1):

You could use reflection to check whether *Control* in fact has a *Content* property...

```
Type t = Ctrl.GetType();
PropertyInfo p = t.GetProperty("Content");
if (p != null)
{
    string val = p.GetValue(Ctrl, null) ?? "";
    val = val.Replace("_", "");
    p.SetValue(Ctrl, val, null);
}
```